# Sorting list of beautifulsoup tag using python

Tags: python, list, sorting, beautifulsoup

I used the script below and extracted a list of url:

```
request = urllib2.Request("http://www.dummyurl.com")
pub_lv1 = urllib2.urlopen(request)
pub_lv1_parse = BeautifulSoup(pub_lv1)
pub_lv1_parse = pub_lv1_parse.body.find('table', attrs={"class":"proxy-archive-content-year-list"})
pub_lv1_parse = pub_lv1_parse.findAll('a')
```

The output is as below:

```
[<a href="/content/by/year/2011">2011</a>,
 <a href="/content/by/year/2012">2012</a>,
 <a href="/content/by/year/2013">2013</a>,
 <a href="/content/by/year/2000">2000</a>,
 <a href="/content/by/year/2001">2001</a>,
 <a href="/content/by/year/2002">2002</a>,
 <a href="/content/by/year/2003">2003</a>,
 <a href="/content/by/year/2004">2004</a>,
 <a href="/content/by/year/2005">2005</a>]
```

As you can see the `year` is not ordered, I want to sort them, I know how to sort a list of string using `sort` but what about output from `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: You can use [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), and pass a function for the `key` parameter, that selects something from each element to compare by. This function would extract the year from each node.

Answer (score 5):

Sort by element text:

```
sorted(pub_lv1_parse, key=lambda elem: elem.text)
```